# Registering BOOT_COMPLETED receiver in Android 8

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

We are about to update our App Android API 26. In the documentation about [Broadcast receiver](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts) it says that

> Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest

Implicit broadcast receivers are described as

> a broadcast that does not target that app specifically. For example, ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED

So I assume that `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` is considered an implicit receiver.

Further it states that implicit receivers must be registered within an `Activity` by using `Context.registerReceiver()`. But that wouldn't make sense for a receiver, which is listening for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event.

What is the proper way to handle this? Can i keep this receiver in my manifest?

Comment: [Implicit Broadcast Exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html).

Comment: Try this way to implement https://github.com/devggaurav/BroadcastReceiver-For-Naught-and-Oreo-devices

Answer (score 19, accepted):

BOOT_COMPLETED is still accepted.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html

No need to change anything. Make sure you test in Android 8.

Comment: Shame for Google with many exceptions. The exceptions are exactly because of bad design.

Answer (score 11):

`ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` is on [the implicit broadcast whitelist](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html), and so you can register for it in the manifest.

Comment: I was wondering that what about native android application? I cannot manage to implement even `BOOT_COMPLETED`, they must be done (I guess). This change started at API 26 and current API is 27. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @efkan: Sorry, but I do not understand your comment. You might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain in greater detail your concerns.

Comment: I'm sorry.. I meant that Google Developers are supposed to use API 27 to develop their native apps like SMS, Duo or Google Drive app. I was wondering that how do they manage to start their app by using `BOOT_COMPLETED` action or using another way? Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: @efkan: Nothing changed with respect to `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` with Android 8.0.

Comment: I've created a new question about it : https://stackoverflow.com/q/47908463/3765109  After I read your articles on your blog I had guessed that somethings are not stable about the newest APIs. After your last comment I started to think that I could have made a mistake in somewhere.

Comment: You can no longer use BOOT_COMPLETED to start a service - it triggers `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent (my_service) : app is in background`

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere: Use `startForegroundService()` on Android 8.0+.