# BOOT_COMPLETED action cannot be received with API 27

Tags: java, android-8.1-oreo

The code below does not receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` action with API 27 although works with API 25.

However this action is among Implicit Broadcast Exeptions according to [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html).

When I enter the adb command of `am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` the message below is shown on the console:

```
Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x400010 } to com.boottest/.OnBootReceiver
```

*Is there any chance to overcome this issue?*

My `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

<application ... >
    ....
    <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver" android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
....
```

My `build.gradle` file:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.boottest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.+"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

My `OnBootReceiver.java` file:

```
package com.boottest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("BootTest", " OnBootReceiver - Received a broadcast!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Rather than using `adb`, do you get control when you reboot the device or emulator? It works fine for me on a Pixel 2, using [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/Intents/OnBoot) modified with the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` set to 27.

Comment: I use Android Emulator and when I restart the emulator the only line regarding my app is that: `W installd: Ignoring /data/data/com.boottest/lib with unexpected GID 0 instead of 10079`. Thank you for taking your time to read my messages :)

Comment: :: shrug :: Try it on hardware. Perhaps it's an emulator issue.

Comment: The problem is Android Emulator. It works on Genymotion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was Android Emulator.

It works as expected and `OnBootReceiver` receiver class evaluates `BOOT_COMPLETED` action on startup when using Genymotion.

Comment: If you are using the new emulator that was released this week, with the snapshot-centric flow, bear in mind that starting up the emulator does not boot the AVD, but simply restores a snapshot. I presume that there is a way to reboot the current emulator, though I haven't looked into it.

Comment: The new emulator provides rebooting the system just like a real device by emulating power button. I've tried both of rebooting and adb command to broadcast `BOOT_COMPLETED` action. They don't work for me. There is another issue I could not figure it out. Also Genymotion is a preview version. No working GPS and network services. I've been trying to run my app with new API changes (like new background execution limits). With emulators will not be easy apparently.