# Android 8.0 - Job Intent Service does not run application on bootup

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, jobintentservice

Initially I had Android 7.0 and didn't have any issues using a `BroadcastReceiver` and service. However with changes to Android 8.0. I needed to switch to a `JobIntentService` so my application can run on bootup.

I have tried migrating my code to match the `JobIntentService` but nothing is happening on bootup. 
I am unsure whether the reason is because of my service class or my `BroadcastReceiver` class.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <service android:name=".backgroundService"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

backgroundService.java

```
    public class backgroundService extends JobIntentService {

        public static final int JOB_ID = 0x01;

        public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
            enqueueWork(context, backgroundService.class, JOB_ID, work);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Application and Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(dialogIntent);
        }
    }
```

startOnBoot.java

```
    public class startOnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
                Log.i("In" , "getAction() - Boot");
                backgroundService.enqueueWork(context, intent);
            }
            else
                Log.i("No" , "Boot");
        }
    }
```

So I am trying to essentially start the `Home.class` on bootup.

Comment: Take a loot at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-do-i-start-my-app-on-startup

Comment: This doesn't help because with android 8.0  you cannot use implicit broadcast receivers so I am trying to use a job intent service. The link doesn't provide any sort of help?

Comment: I think `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` is still accepted on Android 8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981888/registering-boot-completed-receiver-in-android-8

Comment: Well..I have included this in my manifest as well. Still no luck. Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it could run normally. You could check three tips below.

1.Check whether you have declared `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission or not.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

2.Check whether you have declared the receiver with `BOOT_COMPLETED` action.

```
<receiver android:name=".startOnBoot">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

3.Remove `Toast.makeText(this, "Application and Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` in your service or toast it in main thread. Otherwise it gives you the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`.